# Add product SKU in WooCommerce "My account" orders table

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, orders

Currently, this is the text on the woocommerce order table under the total column. (GHS 5.00 for 10 items)

[image: Default total text]

---

I want to display the SKU of the product from the order. So it should be **GHS 5.00 for 10 SKU**.

I have setup the site such that you cannot buy more that one product at a time.

[image: New total text]

---

I use this snippet that's able to change the text am I can't get the product SKU to show

```php
add_filter('ngettext', 'remove_item_count_from_my_account_orders', 105, 3 );
function remove_item_count_from_my_account_orders( $translated, $text, $domain ) {
    switch ( $text ) {
        case '%1$s for %2$s item' :
            $translated = '%1$s';
            break;

        case '%1$s for %2$s items' :
            $translated = '%1$s';
            break;
    }
    return $translated;
}
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to overwrite the text from the total column, but also want to add certain values ​​(such as the sku), you will have to overwrite the existing column.

This can be done via the `woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_{$column_id}` hook.

So you get:

```php
// Overwrite the existing 'order-total' column
function filter_woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_order_total( $order ) {
    // Empty array
    $product_skus = array();

    // Loop through order items
    foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        // Get an instance of corresponding the WC_Product object
        $product = $item->get_product();
        
        // Get product SKU
        $product_sku = $product->get_sku();
    
        // NOT empty
        if ( ! empty ( $product_sku ) ) {
            // Push to array
            $product_skus[] = $product_sku;
        }
    }
    
    // Get item count
    $item_count = $order->get_item_count() - $order->get_item_count_refunded();
    
    // translators: 1: formatted order total 2: total order items
    echo wp_kses_post( sprintf( _n( '%1$s for %2$s ', '%1$s for %2$s ', $item_count, 'woocommerce' ) . implode( ", ", $product_skus ), $order->get_formatted_order_total(), $item_count ) );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_order-total', 'filter_woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_order_total', 10, 1 );
```